# JavaScript execution in a NET Core app on Linux

Tags: javascript, linux, .net-core

I am trying to get some JavaScript to execute in my NET Core 3.1 app on Linux. Not sure if most popular but neither [ClearScript](https://github.com/microsoft/ClearScript) nor [V8.Net](https://github.com/rjamesnw/v8dotnet) seem to work. The former is based on NET Framework and even though the latter supports NET Standard 2.0, neither of the two is fully managed code.

Is there any fully managed code solution, even if lacking features? I need to execute simple expressions.

Comment: ClearScript now supports .NET Core, but only on Windows unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Jint](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint). It's a fully managed solution and runs on all .NET platforms. NuGet package [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Jint).